# Difficulty escaping quote character in powershell script (Azure Devops Yaml)

Tags: powershell, azure-yaml-pipelines

My azure piplines yaml script uses powershell to replace a placeholder string in a .CS file with the current date string. This is the line with the value to be replaced (`20200101000000`)

```
[assembly: MyCompany.Net.Attributes.BuildDateAttribute("20200101000000")]
```

This is the powershell step that does it

```
pwsh: (get-content -path $(versionFile)) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "20200101000000", (get-date -f 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')} | set-content -path $(versionFile)
  displayName: 'Update time stamp file'
```

I want to alter this step to include the quote characters `"` around the search string and write them into the new output value along with the new date.  But I cannot seem to  make that happen.

I mistakenly tried just putting escaped quote characters `\"` in the search and replace strings.  But I guess you cannot escape inside of a single-quoted string so it did not work

```
pwsh: (get-content -path $(versionFile)) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "\"20200101000000\"", (get-date -f '\"yyyyMMddhhmmss\"')} | set-content -path $(versionFile)
```

This was the error:

```
##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\80625e52-1302-4e35-a799-223ab893bcf1.ps1'"
ParserError: D:\a\_temp\80625e52-1302-4e35-a799-223ab893bcf1.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  … lyInfo.cs) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "\"20200101000000\"", (get-d …
     |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unexpected token '20200101000000\""' in expression or statement.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

I also tried to just using double quotes around the `get-date` part of the script so I could escape the quote characters but that doesn't seem to work either.  I'm guessing that's a limitation of writing script this way.

Is there some other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character in Powershell is backtick (`), not backslash (\). Try e.g. `` "`"20200101000000`"" ``.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Get-Date -UFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7#example-4--get-the-date-and-time-with-a-uformat-specifier) instead to add arbitrary characters similar to the `DateTime.ToString()` function in .NET

```
'[Attrib("20200101000000")]' -replace '"20200101000000"', (get-date -UFormat '"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"')
```